# Does the rtweet library have a way to fetch tweets from a specific location?

Tags: r, rtweet

I am trying to get tweets that were tweeted from a specific location e.g. 'LA' using the rtweet package.
I know the twitteR package used to have something of the sort like:

```
a<-searchTwitter("sydney", n=100, geocode='-33.871841,151.206709, 10000mi')
```

where you could even specify the radius.

Is there a way to do add that functionality to the rtweet stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `rtweet`:

```
library(rtweet)
rt <- search_tweets(
  "lang:en", geocode = lookup_coords("usa"), n = 10000
)
```

Stream example from the help page:

```
stream_tweets(
  "realdonaldtrump,trump",
  timeout = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
  file_name = "tweetsabouttrump.json",
  parse = FALSE,
  lookup_coords("usa")
)
```

But you'll need a Google Maps API Key for `lookup_coords` (See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)).

More [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rtweet/versions/0.6.7/topics/search_tweets) and [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rtweet/versions/0.6.7/topics/lookup_coords).

Comment: On the stream tweets section, what if I just wanted to collect the tweets without filtering on anything. Just any tweets being tweeted from the USA. Can I have an empty string there?

Comment: yes, just remove everything you don't need. In this case `"realdonaldtrump,trump"`